# JavaScript - variable "name" has type string and equals null

Tags: javascript

This a bit of code just broke my mind. If I press cancel, the values of `name` and `password` must be `null` but in the `name` case comparison `name == null` returns `false` and `password == null` returns `true`.

```js
var name = prompt('What is your name?', '');
console.log(name);
console.log(name == null); //false

var password = prompt('Password?', '');
console.log(password);
console.log(password == null); //true
```

But if set another name for variable, it works fine

```js
var userName = prompt('What is your name?', '');
console.log(userName);
console.log(userName == null);
```

I made some checking

```js
console.log(typeof name); //String
console.log(name); //null
```

(As I see, `console.log(name);` returns some value in the snippet here)

I've found `name` in [the list of reserved words in JavaScript](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) but I have not found any explanation about this behavior.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, it's exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: `name` is simply property of `window`, as you are running your snippet directly in browser console, your `this` refers to `window` object